# Delete files from folder structure with exclude

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

currently I am trying to delete files inside a folder structure

```
root
|
|__subfolder1 (includes files)
|
|__subfolder2 (includes files)
|
etc
```

The script has to delete all files inside the subfolders except subfolder1 and not delete the subfolders. The thing I am not getting to work is to exclude the files inside of "subfolder1".

I am trying something like this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\root -Include *.* -File -Recurse -Exclude E:\root\subfolder1 | foreach {$_.Delete()}
```

Comment: You say you just want to keep the subfolders, but then you want to keep files from a particular subfolder. Please clarify what you do and don't want deleted.

Comment: I edited the first post. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Is "subfolder1" always directly under the root folder, or can it be anywhere in the folder tree?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It's always directly under root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the subfolder you want to exclude is always directly under the root folder I'd do the processing in 2 steps:

- Enumerate the child folders of the root folder and exclude `subfolder1`.
- Enumerate all files from the remaining folders and delete them.

Something like this:

```
$root     = 'root'
$excludes = 'subfolder1'

Get-ChildItem $root -Directory -Exclude $excludes | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -File -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Force
}
```